# Jquery using slice to show Li's based on Clicks

Tags: jquery, click, slice

I have 3 items that I want to show at one time. I have 4 in total. If the user clicks on the left arrow it should take them back an item by subtracting from the start and end, if they hit right arrow it should add to the start and the end. My problem is that when I click to go forward it doesnt add or subtract when going backwards. This is probably fairly simple. Here is my code. Again, unless I am going about this the wrong way, I want my start index and my end index to change when you click the right arrow or the left arrow.  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/cnqM7/4/)

```
$(function() {
    var backLi = 0;
    var forwardLi = 3;
      var end = forwardLi + 1;           

 if (end == $(".divsize ul li").length) end = undefined;
    $(".divsize ul li").css({"display" : "none"});
 if (end)   
    $(".divsize ul li").slice(backLi , forwardLi).addClass("showItem");


    $(".rightArr").click(function() {
        backLi = backLi + 1;
        forwardLi = forwardLi + 1;
        $('input.forward').val(backLi);
        $('input.backLi').val(forwardLi);     
    });     

    $(".leftArr").click(function(){
        backLi = backLi - 1;
        forwardLi = forwardLi - 1;
        $('input.forward').val(backLi);
        $('input.backLi').val(forwardLi);
    });
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Shouldn't your syntax be: `backLi = backLi + 1` vs what you have in your conditionals? Otherwise, every time you click them they just change to 1 or -1. There's not any adding/subtracting taking place.

Comment: I see what your saying I will make that change and see what changes. thank you.

Comment: That made no change to my issue at hand, see my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cornelas/cnqM7/2/

Comment: I have a input box that is watching for a change just in case any other part of my code isnt working, it did not change in value.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the docs, I don't like your syntax. See if this jQuery code fixes your issue:

```
    var backLi = 0;
    var forwardLi = 2;
    $(".divsize ul li").slice(backLi , forwardLi);
    $(".rightArr").click(function() {
        console.log(backLi, forwardLi);
        backLi = backLi + 1;
        forwardLi = forwardLi + 1;
        $('input.forward').val(backLi);
        return false;
    })      
    $(".leftArr").click(function() {
        console.log(backLi, forwardLi);
        backLi = backLi - 1;
        forwardLi = forwardLi - 1;
        $('input.forward').val(backLi);
        return false;
    })
```

btw - you have lefttArr (extra 't') instead of leftArr in your code.

Comment: I have made a few changes to my code that I am going to upload here shortly, but im close to, it I caught the lefttarr oops, what im doing now is adding the class to show the items that between backLi and forwardLi just finishing the if statement now.